# angularjs video upload with thumbnail

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have tried with creating directives but is is not working properly so please
if anyone have please share the video upload with thumbnail code as early as possible  and thank u in advance

```
angular
    .module('chotaMangoAdmin')
    .directive('fileUpload', fileModel);

    fileModel.$inject = [ '$parse' ];
    ngThumb.$inject = ['$window'];

    function fileModel($parse) {
        return {
           scope:true,        //create a new scope
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {   
              element.bind('change', function(event){
                 var files = event.target.files;
                 console.log(files.length);
                 scope.$emit("fileSelected", { images: files });
              });
           }
        };
    }
```

Comment: you can use https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

Comment: thank you heemanshu-bhalla i will try it later..

Comment: ok let me know if it is useful for you

Comment: heemanshu i am getting service injector problem if you have full code please mail me. and my mail id is desai.abhijit2014@gmail.com

Comment: here is source code link -
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/archive/master.zip

Comment: thank u  Heemanshu Bhalla

Comment: I am going to add this as answer please mark it if its useful for you so that it can help others also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/0mz6ff9o/135/ use this Sa E Chowdary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery File Upload Demo
AngularJS version**

File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&drop support, progress bars, validation and preview images, audio and video for AngularJS.
Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and client-side image resizing.

Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.

[See Demo](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html)

[Download Source Code From GitHub](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/archive/master.zip)